# Show time diff as HH:MM:SS between two datetimes in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I got two different datetimes: `2020-05-18 12:30:01` and `2020-05-17 13:00:00`.
I want to show the time difference between them in the format `HH:MM:SS`, which is `23:30:01`.

If the difference is higher than 24 hours, let's say 28 hours, 12 minutes and 45 seconds, it would show like `28:12:45`.

How can I do that in SQLite?

Comment: If the difference is greater than 24 hours what should be the result?

Comment: @forpas let's say 26:30:01 for example, it still counts the number of hours normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite supports a limited number of functions for datetime manipulation.
One of these functions is `strftime()`, and

```
strftime('%s', somedate)
```

returns the number of seconds from `'1970-01-01'` up to `somedate`.

With the use of this function, arithmetic calculations, string padding and concatenations you can get what you want like this:

```
  CASE WHEN ((strftime('%s', date1) - strftime('%s', date2)) / 3600) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END ||
  ((strftime('%s', date1) - strftime('%s', date2)) / 3600) || ':' ||   
  SUBSTR('0' || (((strftime('%s', date1) - strftime('%s', date2)) / 60) % 60), -2) || ':' ||   
  SUBSTR('0' || ((strftime('%s', date1) - strftime('%s', date2)) % 60), -2)
```

Replace `date1` and `date2` with your dates.

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXtmyoUqZj9PyoucnXamQm/0).

Comment: Ah, a little creative thinking goes a long way, thanks. I used this as base to solve one of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time(
(
  julianday('2020-05-18 12:30:01')-
  julianday('2020-05-17 13:00:00')
)*60*60*24, 'unixepoch'
);
```

answsers the question when time difference is lower than 24h...

Comment: This returns 23:30:01 even if the 1st date is 2020-05-19 12:30:01. The correct result shoud be 47:30:01.